# UIScrollView With next and previous button Action

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am new in iphone,i am using horizontal scrollview these are horizontally scrolling properly
  but i want these horizontally scrolling on previous and next button action.please help me asap.

Thanks:)

Comment: What do the next and previous buttons do?

Comment: I guess he means scroll buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps that was worked for me

in .h file write following code.

```
int scrollMove; 
UIScrollView *aScrView;

-(IBAction)nextBtnAction:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)previousBtnAction:(id)sender;
```

in .m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

scrollMove=50;

aScrView=[[UIScrollView alloc]init];
aScrView.frame=CGRectMake(25,50, 270, 50);
aScrView.delegate=self;
aScrView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(1200, 0);

[self.view addSubview:aScrView];


// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}


-(IBAction)nextBtnAction:(id)sender{

 float coordinate = 2.0f;
 //scrollMove=50;
 [aScrView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollMove * coordinate, 0) animated:YES];
 scrollMove=scrollMove+50;



 }
-(IBAction)previousBtnAction:(id)sender{
float coordinate = 1.0f;


[aScrView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollMove * coordinate, 0) animated:YES];
scrollMove=scrollMove-50;
}
```

Hope this helps you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use this one when you want to go on next visible content of Scroll view:

(Put this one inside next button method)

```
float coordinate = 2.0f;
[nodeScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(460 * coordinate, 0) animated:YES];
```

move on previous visible content view:

```
float coordinate = 1.0f;

[nodeScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(460 * coordinate, 0) animated:YES];
```

(Put this one inside previous button method)

****You need some mathematical calculation with coordinate

Comment: Thanks i have implemented ur code that was successful, button actions are performed only one time and i want after one time click go to one page and again click go second page and same thing on previous button action.so plz help me asap. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * pageNumberYouWantToGoTo;
frame.origin.y = 0;
[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    x=0;
    y=320;
}

- (IBAction)next:(id)sender 

{
    y=320;
    [scrl_Knot setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x+320,0) animated:YES];
    x+=320;

}

- (IBAction)pre:(id)sender 

{

    x=0;
    [scrl_Knot setContentOffset:CGPointMake(y,0) animated:YES];
    y-=320;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)pre:(id)sender
{
    btnNext.enabled = TRUE;
    imageID--;
    [scrl_venuelist setContentOffset:CGPointMake(imageID*273, 0) animated:YES];
    pagecontrol.currentPage=imageID;
    if(imageID <= 0)
    {
        btnPrevious.enabled = FALSE;
    }
}
- (IBAction)next:(id)sender
{
    btnPrevious.enabled = TRUE;
    imageID++;
    [scrl_venuelist setContentOffset:CGPointMake(imageID*273, 0) animated:YES];
    pagecontrol.currentPage=imageID;
    if(imageID >= imageArr.count-1)
    {
        btnNext.enabled = FALSE;
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView; 
{
    imageID = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width; 
    pagecontrol.currentPage=imageID;

    if(imageID <= 0)
    {
        btnPrevious.enabled = FALSE;
        imageID = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        btnPrevious.enabled = TRUE;
    }

    if(imageID >= imageArr.count-1)
    {
        btnNext.enabled = FALSE;
        imageID = imageArr.count-1;
    }
    else
    {
        btnNext.enabled = TRUE; 
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    scrl_venuelist.delegate=self;
    scrl_venuelist.contentSize =CGSizeMake(273 * [imageArr count], 137);
    if(imageID == 0)
    {
        btnPrevious.enabled = FALSE;
        if(imageID == imageArr.count-1)
        {
            btnNext.enabled = FALSE;
        }
    }
    else if(imageID == imageArr.count-1)
    {
        btnNext.enabled = FALSE;
    }
    else if(imageID > imageArr.count-1)
    {
        imageID = [imageArr count]-1;
    }
    scrl_venuelist.pagingEnabled=YES;
    pagecontrol.numberOfPages=[imageArr count];
    pagecontrol.currentPage=0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If Any one Looking for way of doing in C# for Xamarin

```
    public int CurrentIndex
    {
        get => (int)Math.Round(this.scrollView.ContentOffset.X / this.scrollView.Frame.Width);
        set => this.scrollView.ScrollRectToVisible(new CGRect(new CGPoint(this.scrollView.Frame.Size.Width * value, 0), this.scrollView.Frame.Size), true);
    }
```

This getter and Setter should provide you current page as well let you scroll to the specified page

On Button Actions Just Update Current Index to new Values, Which could current Index +1/-1.